# How to add on Change listener in Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, ontouchlistener

In my Android Application. i am having one EditText and Textview.in Edittext user need
      to enter the amount. while he entering the amount in edit text , in textview it has to
      display the total value (addition of tax value). How to do this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use textwatcher for that.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a TextWatcher as a TextChangeListener for your EditText:

```
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
             mTextView.setText(mEditText.getText().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
EditText Et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
Et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // You need to write your code here when user need to enter the amount.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added sample code, which continuously watch edittext changes and do some operation, then update that values in the textview. I hope this will help. Plz follow the naming conventions.

EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

```
    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            TextView twxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Double sum = 0.00;
            Double userValue = 0.00;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                userValue = Double.valueOf(s.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sum = 2 * (sum + userValue);
            twxt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much dayana... it is very useful and perfectly matched with my scenario. Thank you

Comment: Your TextView should not be declared within your onTextChanged method. It isn't efficient that way (every time the user writes or deletes a character, the findViewById will be called).